# Goodness of fit test 'ncores' argument produces error if included or if left to default

Tags: r, model, statistics-bootstrap, goodness-of-fit

I (a novice) am trying to run a McKenzie-Bailey goodness of fit test on occupancy models using package `AICcmodavg.` No matter what I do I get an error regarding argument `ncores` which specifies how many of my computational cores to use in running the bootstraps. The package info says that if left blank it will default to 1 less than available cores. My computer has 4 cores. If I specify any number of cores (I've tried 0-4) I get an error that the argument is unused. If I do not specify `ncores` I get an error that it is missing. Code following, any suggestions appreciated :)

```
mb.gof.test(CamMod1, nsim = 1000, ncores = 3)
```

> Error in statistic(object, ...) : unused argument (ncores = ncores)

```
mb.gof.test(CamMod1, nsim = 1000)
```

> Error in parboot(mod, statistic = function(i) mb.chisq(i)$chi.square,  : argument "ncores" is missing, with no default

Comment: Can you show us what `class(CamMod1)` is?  A reproducible example would be even better ...

Comment: In the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AICcmodavg/versions/2.3-1/topics/mb.gof.test) it doesn't take `ncores = XX` as an argument, it just takes `ncores`, so does `mb.gof.test(CamMod1, nsim = 1000, 3)` work for you?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Class(CamMod1) tells me my model is "unmarkedFitOccu" this is an occupancy model in program unmarked and is what the mg.got.test is designed to look at. Unfortunately I don't think it would be easy to make reproducible.

Comment: Jared-Marmot, that was a great idea I hadn't tried yet. Still have me the error: "argument "ncores" is missing, with no default"

Comment: I tried the same test on a different computer and it worked... so there is something funky going on with my version of r studio I'm guessing...